# unable to read .replit: unable to decode .replit: Near line 5 (last key parsed 'run'): Key 'run' has already been defined

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

so effectively I am tryinning to run a Django website that i can share the link. The issue is the RUN file with the .replit file. I need to pip install crispy forms then run the server. How can this be accomplished in the .replit file?

tried the following:

```
language = "python3"

run = "pip install django-crispy-forms"

run = "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:3000"
```

Comment: See the replit Docs on [Installing Packages](https://docs.replit.com/repls/packages/).

Comment: I tried that and no success

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple `run` lines. Poetry (built-in, no setup required) should automatically install the modules you need, but in case it doesn't try this instead:

```
language = "python3"

run = "pip install django-crispy-forms && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:3000"
```